# js framework for small web application

Tags: javascript, webforms

In past I used knockout.js and backbone.js for building single page small applications where i had few user input forms and data lists with sub items.

In knockout binding observables is not clean and also observables does not work if your list have child items. For multiple forms code becomes too messy.

initially i liked backbone but i was amazed when i was not able to find any  solution for cascading dropdown, rather dropdown its self was quite hard.

I'm looking for some better js framework/library for this kind of applications. I reviewed some angular and react examples and it looks like it will be overkill using such framework for a small app.

Comment: Recommendations are off topic, and an opinionated criterion like "better" is a good example of why.

Comment: ok updating my question, btw where can i ask question to experienced person to find a better choice ? thanks

Comment: the good thing about react is that it can be very small.  You can use it with vanilla js and make your forms in one small js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can react for only small parts of your site. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) are the docs for using it without compiling anything.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm still looking any other solutions.